# Ctrl+x produces strange behaviour

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, xkb

All my other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts are working perfectly (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> for copying etc). But when I type <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> nothing happens. I used `xev` to display what's happening when I press <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>.

This is the output when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>:

```
#Pressing Ctrl
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17087932, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

#Pressing c
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17088261, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x4, keycode 31 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

#Releasing c
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17088376, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x4, keycode 31 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False

#Releasing Ctrl
KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17088675, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

But this is what's happening when typing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17089955, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x0, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusOut event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   32  0   16  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17090318, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x4, keycode 52 (keysym 0x78, x), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (18) "▒"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x6400001,
    root 0x933, subw 0x0, time 17090555, (110,100), root:(110,129),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I also realized that whenever pressing <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> the mouse pointer dissappeares until I move it, which is caused by the `FocusOut event`. This happens with all keyboard layouts.

**Edit:**
This does not happen with i3, but only on KDE, so it seems to be a KDE-related issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to find out more about the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I switched to i3, where I don't have this problem.